# Downloading a segment of a youtube video and cropping it precisely

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have an interesting little problem.

I want to download a specific section of a youtube video, this is easy enough to do with the magic of `yt-dlp`:

```bash
yt-dlp -f "(bestvideo+bestaudio)[protocol!*=dash]" --external-downloader ffmpeg
  --external-downloader-args "ffmpeg_i:-ss 672.46 -to 677.15" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U7Sbl-DXcI"
```

The problem is, this often results in extra content at the start or end of the video due to where the keyframes are.

A solution to this is to re-encode the video with a specific start and end point.

Again, this is quite straightforward:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.webm -ss 672.46 -to 677.15 -c:v libvpx -c:a copy
  -crf 40 -b:v 500k -vf scale=480:-2 output.webm
```

The thing is, I don't want to have to download the entire video only to extract a small segment.

The solution I thought of was to do the following:

1. download the imprecise video+audio segment as before
2. download a precise *audio only* segment (I'm assuming this is possible because there are no keyframes)
3. **now the tricky bit. somehow figure out how the audio file aligns with the audio track in the imprecise video segment.**
4. use the offset to re-encode the right portion of the imprecise video segment.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can approach step 3? Or maybe can suggest an alternative approach?

Edit:

It doesn't seem like it's straightforward to download a precise segment of audio using yt-dlp.. does anyone know if this is a limitation of the tool, or just not possible? I'm guessing the seeking depends on the video track and the audio track can't be seeked in the same way?